# Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers: change default root directory

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I am using Remote-Containers extension on VSCode to work directly on my running containers.
The project hierarchy of my container looks like this:

```
angular_container
    /usr/
        src/
            app/
                frontend/
                    my-source-files
```

I right-click my container and select the 'Attach Visual Studio Code' option. By default, this opens the /usr/src/app/src/ directory on my container, which doesn't exist.
Is there a way to change this setting so that VSCode opens the /usr/src/app/ directory instead? The Remote - Containers extension settings does not specify anything like this.

Comment: I can't believe nobody upvoted you. Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 20):

Maybe, you selected it by default but you can change it:

Open the command list:
Shift + Ctrl + P

Search for this command and select it:
**Remote-Containers: Open attached container configuration file**

Select your container from the list, this will open your configuration.

Something like this:

```
{
    "workspaceFolder": "/root",
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-toolsai.jupyter"
    ]
}
```

Change the workspaceFolder with your desired.

Save and re attach the container.

Comment: I can't believe nobody upvoted you. Thanks.

Comment: On macbook, the command is Shift + Command + p and then enter **Dec Containers: Open attached container configuration file**